# Changing block content based on user input

Tags: 7, blocks

I need to change the content of a block on the landing page based on user input.
Basically, I have a few links and a search form; if the user clicks on a link, I want the block to display some text, based on which link was clicked, and if the user uses the search form then to display information from an external database.

**Edit**
I left this site for a while & now am coming back to it.
I thought about it and if it's too hard to do in a module, then I could just make different pages for the texts & link them. And displaying data from the database is trivial.

Comment: How is your block created?  Is it through code/views/standard etc?

Comment: can you code PHP?

Comment: @Chapabu - standard.

Comment: @Mawg a little, though I won't have a problem learning as I already know a couple of languages.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.